How to write this system in state-space form and then derive its transfer function?
For a system modeled by  a linear differential equation of the form:
$$a_n\frac{d^{n} y(t)}{dt^{n}}+\cdots +a_{1}\frac{d y(t)}{dt}+a_{0}y(t)=b_m\frac{d^{m} x(t)}{dt^{m}}+\cdots+b_{1}\frac{d x(t)}{dt}+b_{0}x(t)$$ we can get the transfer function of the system by directly applying the Laplace transform on both sides: $$\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}=\frac{b_ms^m+\cdots+b_{1}s+b_{0}}{a_ns^n+\cdots +a_{1}s+a_{0}}$$ But I don't know how this transfer function can be derived using a state-space representation $$\displaystyle {\dot {\mathbf {x} }}(t)=A \mathbf {x} (t)+B \mathbf {u} (t) \\ \displaystyle \mathbf {y} (t)=C \mathbf {x} (t)+D \mathbf {u} (t)$$ I want the input vector $\mathbf {u} (t) = x(t)$ and the output vector to be equal to $\mathbf {y} (t)=y(t)$, and then derive the transfer function of the system using $W(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D$, how can this be done?

Would one solution be sufficient like in this answer (since there are infinitely many equivalent state space representations under similarity transformation)?
